# How to send a file using Body binary in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, postman

I can upload a file in Postman using Body - binary and 
Content-Dispostion Header with values 'binary-data' and path to filename

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEu4Q.png)

[Postman Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shr8v.png)

[Jmeter Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdoZF.png)

for Jmeter request I am just getting 400. I'd like to know how I can add Body binary file path to Jmeter request?
Thanks

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGQ8N.png)
[Jmeter request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BjD6.png)

Comment: Did you get solution about your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove in JMeter header manager the 2 rows that have empty values and are above Content-Disposition
also fix the value of Content-Disposition to remove the spaces

If it still fails show JMeter HTtP Request

Comment: Thank you. The two rows are not empty, they are custom headers for this request and I don't see any spaces. I updated description with request screenshot.